# Can't link to sites without the https:// URL

Tags: php, html

I can't link to sites that don't use the `https://` starting URL. For example, I can link to google because it started with `http://`, but I can't link to stackoverflow, because it doesn't. I'm using a web server called ipage, and my domain is in a sub directory.

When I click on the stackoverflow link, it brings me to a page like this: www.mydomainname.com/www.stackoverflow.com.

```
<a href = 'https://www.google.com/'> https://www.google.com/ </a>
<a href = 'www.stackoverflow.com'> www.stackoverflow.com </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this approach

```
<a href = '//www.google.com/'> https://www.google.com/ </a>
<a href = '//www.stackoverflow.com'> www.stackoverflow.com </a>
```

and it will work fine.

just remove `http` and `https` from start and put `//` infront

Comment: actually, you'll have to supply `http` OR `https` in url while linking to external sources.
and if you don't know the protocols, just place `//` and server will take care of rest.